# Why Not Getting Undefined Index Error On One When I Get On The Other That Is Practically The Same Code?

Tags: php, undefined

Folks,

Look at this code. It gives no error:

```
//WORKING FINE
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
echo __LINE__;
echo "<br>";

if(!session_id() || !isset($_SESSION['form_step']) || $_SESSION['form_step'] != 'end')
{
    echo __LINE__;
    echo "<br>";
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
    echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>";
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
    echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo __LINE__;
    echo "<br>";
}
elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')
{
    echo __LINE__;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>";
    echo __LINE__;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

And look at this one that gives error:
**Notice: Undefined index: form_step in C:\xampp\htdocs\power.page\pagination_test_SIMPLE.php on line 143**

```
//WHY GIVES UNDEFINED ERROR ON LINE: elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
echo __LINE__;
echo "<br>";

if(!session_id())
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['form_step']) || $_SESSION['form_step'] != 'end')
    {
        echo __LINE__;
        echo "<br>";
        $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
        echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo session_id();
        echo "<br>";
        $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
        echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo __LINE__;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')
{
    echo __LINE__;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>";
    echo __LINE__;
    echo "<br>";
}
die;
```

Both codes are practically the same. I just changed this line from the 1st code:

```
if(!session_id() || !isset($_SESSION['form_step']) || $_SESSION['form_step'] != 'end')
{
```

to this line in the 2nd code:

```
if(!session_id())
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['form_step']) || $_SESSION['form_step'] != 'end')
    {
```

That is all. The 2nd code giving the error.
Q1. How come the 1st code is not giving that same error ?

Comment: And which line is line 143 exactly

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Your question's answer was in the comment of the 2nd code. Anyway, this shows UNDEFINED INDEX error:
elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')
{

Comment: Oh right, so it is (ish)

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because in the second code you only test

```
if(!session_id())
```

and then in the else, which you go to if there is a session started

```
elseif($_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')
```

you have not actually checked that the specific `$_SESSION['form_step']` actually exists, you have just assumed it will, and obviously in some case(s), it will not yet exist.

Comment: I understand now that on the 1st code, the:
if(!session_id()
is not triggering the IF but the:
!isset($_SESSION['form_step']) || $_SESSION['form_step'] != 'end')'
is triggering it and during the trigger, the:
$_SESSION['form_step']
is getting defined.
Hence, when I refresh the page, on the 2nd round the ELSEIF is getting triggered and it finds the:
$_SESSION['form_step']
defined. Hence, shows no problem.

While with the 2nd code, unlike the 1st code, the ELSEIF is getting triggered first and it finds the:
$_SESSION['form_step']
not defined yet and so gives the error.

Thanks!

Comment: You see, I thought on the 1st code, the:

if(!session_id() 

was triggering the IF. But it actually wasn't. That wrong thinking of mine was taking me off track to confusion!